# React Typescript No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type s

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What should i do to not catch error in this situation?

I have component that display categories.

```
categories = ['Branded','Foundation','Survey (FNDDS)','SR Legacy', 'Experimental']
```

And i want to display number of items that contain each of this category
near its name,
this information I receive from server in this object:

```
aggregations: {
        dataType: {
            "Branded"?: number,
            "Survey (FNDDS)"?: number,
            "SR Legacy"?: number,
            "Foundation"?: number,
            "Experimental"?: number
        }
    }
```

But when I try get this number using this syntax:

```
data.aggregations.dataType[category]
```

I get error:

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an  any  type because expression of type  string  can't be used to index type
No index signature with a parameter of type  string  was found on type
```

If i supress ts error its work like i want

Comment: The error basically says that `category` can be any string e.g `test`. `data.aggregations.dataType['test']` doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare proper type to `category` so it corresponds to the properties on your object.

```
let categories = ['Branded', 'Foundation', 'Survey (FNDDS)', 'SR Legacy', 'Experimental'] as const
type Category = typeof categories[number]

// type declaration for your API object
type ApiObject = {
  aggregations: {
    dataType: {
      [key in Category]?: number
    }
  }
}

// your actual API object
let obj:ApiObject = {
  aggregations: {
    dataType: {
      'Branded': 1,
      'Survey (FNDDS)': 4
    }
  }
}

// category needs to be declared as Category type
let category:Category = 'Branded'
let val = obj.aggregations.dataType[category]
```